# Headless PDE Build and Java Compiler Compliance

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

My problem is that I am looking to update a feature-based build.properties file so that the headless build process will use the Java JRE/JDK 1.6 release but will be compliant against the Java JRE/JDK 1.5 release.

How would this be acheived in a headless build through the build.properties file (i.e., which properties would be set and to what values)?

I am thinking of some combination of setting values for the JavaSE-1.6, javaSource, and javaTarget properties, as shown below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
############# JAVA COMPILER OPTIONS ##############
# The location of the Java jars to compile against.  Typically the rt.jar
#  for your JDK/JRE
#bootclasspath=${java.home}/lib/rt.jar

# specific JRE locations to compile against. These values are used to compile
#  bundles specifying a Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment. Uncomment and set
#  values for environments that you support
#CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0= /path/to/rt.jar
#CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1=
#OSGi/Minimum-1.0=
#OSGi/Minimum-1.1=
#JRE-1.1=
#J2SE-1.2=
#J2SE-1.3=
#J2SE-1.4=
#J2SE-1.5=
JavaSE-1.6=${java.home}/lib/rt.jar
#PersonalJava-1.1=
#PersonalJava-1.2=
#CDC-1.0/PersonalBasis-1.0=
#CDC-1.0/PersonalJava-1.0i=
#CDC-1.1/PersonalBeclipseasis-1.1=
#CDC-1.1/PersonalJava-1.1=

...

# Default value for the version of the source code. This value is used when
#  compiling plug-ins that do not set the Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment
#  or set javacSource in build.properties
javacSource=1.5

# Default value for the version of the byte code targeted. This value is used
#  when compiling plug-ins that do not set the
#  Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment or set javacTarget in build.properties.
javacTarget=1.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing this in your PDE Build, why don't you set Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment in your plugins to Java 5? The manifest editor in PDE will help you set it to the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up Konstantin!  The bundles currently have this property set in the MANIFEST.MF file so that is already set.  I assumed by providing the default values of 1.5 for both the javacSource and javacTarget would cover any bundles that might have this property changed or not supplied (e.g., future bundles).

As far as setting the JavaSE-1.6 property, does this tell PDE to use the Java JDK/JRE 1.6 distribution?  My utlimate goal is to have 1.6 be used when more than one version of the JRE/JDK exists on the same machine.  Would this be controlled only by the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: PDE build determines the ideal Java version that a given plugin needs to be built with based on plugin metadata. Then it looks at your build.properties to find the matching JDK. If it doesn't find matching one, it searches for fall-back versions. Ideally, you should build with what's the plugin's minimum compatibility level. That will not only set language level appropriately, but also catch accidental use of classes introduced in a newer version of Java.